# Two data sources in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot app for which I have configured two data sources. So far I've configured the data sources in my `Application` class (annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`):

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.db1")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.db2")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

I also added the configuration values to `application.properties`:

```
datasource.db1.url=...
...
datasource.db2.url=...
...
```

Since `db1` is the `@Primary` data source, it is chosen by default. How do I tell an interface extending `JpaRepository` that it should use `db2` instead?

UPDATE: mentioning that my repository is an interface.

Comment: coudl you use a different Persitence Unit? Have a look here: http://xantorohara.blogspot.de/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use this approach with Repository interfaces, that Spring uses to automatically generate implementations.

Comment: I think here you have a simple example: http://scattercode.co.uk/2013/11/18/spring-data-multiple-databases/

Comment: @Patrick: A half a minute too late. Found that too... first google hit "spring data multiple data sources"

Comment: Possible duplicate :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200035/how-to-get-spring-data-to-handle-multiple-heterogeneous-datasources

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bean associated to the secondary data source from the application context.
For example in `Application.java` (I'm also using Spring Boot) you define:

```
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

and in a service (here for calling a stored procedure) you have:

```
@Service
public class EngineImpl implements EngineDao {

    private SetScartiProcedure setScarti;   

    @Autowired  
    public void init(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) ctx.getBean("secondaryDataSource");
        this.setScarti = new SetScartiProcedure(dataSource);
    }

    public class SetScartiProcedure extends StoredProcedure {
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

based on  [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html) you can define several `DataSource`this way

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean customerEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder
            .dataSource(customerDataSource())
            .packages(Customer.class)
            .persistenceUnit("customers")
            .build();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean orderEntityManagerFactory(
        EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder
            .dataSource(orderDataSource())
            .packages(Order.class)
            .persistenceUnit("orders")
            .build();
}
```

and then bind each one of them to different classes that each one of them manages

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Customer.class,
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "customerEntityManagerFactory")
public class CustomerConfiguration {
    ...
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = Order.class,
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "orderEntityManagerFactory")
public class OrderConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

the repositories should know which database to use by the `DataSource` that was bidden to the class