# How to get Spring Data to handle multiple heterogeneous DataSources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-boot

I've been successful using using the [Accessing Data With JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) tutorial for Spring. I've gotten a CrudRepository of my own to work automatically by just configuring a specific DataSource @Bean, and the internal connections between these are managed by Spring Data (or Spring Boot, it's hard to tell which).

However, I can't figure out how to get that automated plumbing to handle a second DataSource @Bean. Injecting a second one causes the autoconfiguration classes to explode during startup.

Any thoughts as to how to do this? The searches I've done for this resulted in articles discussing multiple *homogeneous* DataSources for load balancing or other purposes, which is really not what I need. I have multiple databases with completely separate content that I need to pull into this app and I'd really like to avoid having to replicate all that automated configuration just because a second database entered the mix.

I'm hoping this is simple, but I'm fearful that it's an unsupported edge case in the autoconfiguration.

Comment: Are you using the Repository annotation? If so did you setup a Configuration class or xml config with EnableRepos? If both those are true, I bet you are missing an Qualifier annotation. Since they both extend the Repo interface, there is an autowire conflict. Adding Qualifier('datasource1') Qualifier('datasource2') your injections can simply add the qualifier for the source thats important to the service.

Comment: @AnthonyJClink I'm not using the Repository annotation, I'm simply extending the CrudRepository interface as shown at https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: You may want to rephrase your title, as you're talking about backing different types from different backends of the same kind (SQL), not Spring Data cross-store support.

Comment: if you are adding second datasources in spring-boot you need to mark one of them as a @Primary in order to be recognize by autoconfiguration.

Comment: @chrylis I'm unclear how my title suggests "cross-store support".

Comment: It's not clear whether "heterogeneous" means "multiple types of backend" or "multiple instances of the same type of backend with partitioned schemas".

Comment: They're both SQL backends but appear to require distinct configuration because they use different SQL dialects and JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two datasources and entitymanagers, one bean of them mark as @Primary

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "io.eddumelendez.springdatajpa.repository1")
public class FirstConfiguration {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.postgres")
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().
                build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf1(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
        return builder
                .dataSource(postgresDataSource())
                .packages("io.eddumelendez.springdatajpa.domain1")
                .persistenceUnit("users")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Configuration for another datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "io.eddumelendez.springdatajpa.repository2", entityManagerFactoryRef = "emf2")
public class SecondConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.mysql")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf2(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
        return builder
                .dataSource(mysqlDataSource())
                .packages("io.eddumelendez.springdatajpa.domain2")
                .persistenceUnit("customers")
                .build();
    }

}
```

Your application.properties should looks like this:

```
datasource.mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_demo
datasource.mysql.username=root
datasource.mysql.password=root

datasource.postgres.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres_demo
datasource.postgres.username=postgres
datasource.postgres.password=postgres
```

Comment: How would I go about using the non-Primary DataSource, though? Would I need to build the plumbing for that all manually?

Comment: Primary annotation will be used by the auto-configuration only, just to don't break it. If you are using JdbcTemplate you have to inject the DataSource with the correct Qualifier annotation in order to know  which datasource will be used.

Comment: I'm not using JdbcTemplate, I'm using CrudRepository because it handles everything for me. However the only way I've seen those constructed are through the auto-configuration that won't apparently work with more than one DataSource.

Comment: I have updated the configuration, so with that you could work with Repositories

Comment: What versions of the Spring libraries is that code for? It doesn't compile with Spring 4.1.4, Spring Boot 1.2.1, and Spring Data JPA 1.7.1.

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. I was importing the wrong EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.

Comment: Yes, that it! I was switching to the version. But you find the missing import.